# Find new coordinates of a point after rotation

Tags: math

Suppose i have a rectangle of dimension w*h , and let there is an arbitrary point inside this rectangle at position (x,y) , now i rotate this rectangle to X degree, What will be the new position of that arbitrary point after rotation..

Comment: Which point is the center of rotation?

Comment: The center of rotation is the center of the rectangle.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Math related questions better ask here http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and it belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 43):

If `a` is an angle in radians of a **counterclockwise** rotation, then the new coordinate (x',y') is

```
x' = x*cos(a) - y*sin(a)
y' = x*sin(a) + y*cos(a)
```

If `a` is an angle in radians of a **clockwise** rotation, then the new coordinate (x',y') is

```
x' =  x*cos(a) + y*sin(a)
y' = -x*sin(a) + y*cos(a)
```

If the angle you're given is in degrees `d`, then convert to radians `a` first via

```
a = d * pi / 180
```

Comment: your answer is wrong, it is `y' = y*cos(a) + x*sin(a)`, `x' = - y*sin(a) + x*cos(a)` instead.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ Yes that is typically the convention in mathematics, that `a` is an angle of a counter-clockwise rotation. In computer graphics, it is sometimes expected to be clockwise, which is what this answer assumed. Thanks for pointing the ambiguity out; the answer has been updated.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ so for a clockwise rotation, is it supposed to be `x' = -y*sin(a) + x*cos(a)`, i.e., the sum's first half should be negated?

Comment: @Matt What if the center of rotation should have been the center of the image, instead of (0,0)?

Comment: @quantumflash Translate the center of the image to (0,0), rotate, then translate it back.