# New coordinates after image rotation using scipy.ndimage.rotate

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, scipy

The image is an array of (250,250,3). The image is rotated by a degree using

image = scipy.ndimage.rotate(image, deg, reshape=False)

There're two points on the image, and the points after rotation is calculated by

```
deg = deg*np.pi/180
x_new = y*np.sin(deg) + x*np.cos(deg)
y_new = y *np.cos(deg) - x*np.sin(deg)
```

Following the post [Find new coordinates of a point after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104611/find-new-coordinates-of-a-point-after-rotation)

However, the point position after rotation is not as expected:
[Image before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvUcd.png)  [Image after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYFWH.png)

The points are not fixed at the position of people's eye. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This question has now got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657423/rotated-image-coordinates-after-scipy-ndimage-interpolation-rotate