# Rotated image coordinates after scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, rotation

I have a numpy array for an image that I read in from a FITS file. I rotated it by N degrees using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate`. Then I want to figure out where some point (x,y) in the original non-rotated frame ends up in the rotated image -- i.e., what are the rotated frame coordinates (x',y')?

This should be a very simple rotation matrix problem but if I do the usual mathematical or programming based rotation equations, the new (x',y') do not end up where they originally were. I suspect this has something to do with needing a translation matrix as well because the scipy rotate function is based on the origin (0,0) rather than the actual center of the image array.

Can someone please tell me how to get the rotated frame (x',y')? As an example, you could use

```
from scipy import misc
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
data_orig = misc.face()
data_rot = rotate(data_orig,66) # data array
x0,y0 = 580,300 # left eye; (xrot,yrot) should point there
```

P.S. The following two related questions' answers do not help me:

- [Find new coordinates of a point after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104611/find-new-coordinates-of-a-point-after-rotation?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [New coordinates after image rotation using scipy.ndimage.rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538035/new-coordinates-after-image-rotation-using-scipy-ndimage-rotate)

Comment: Can you provide an example (or examples) with which we can test the correctness of our solution?

Comment: I just added an example using scipy's own misc racoon face and an original (x,y) point at the left eye. The new (xrot,yrot) in the rotated frame by 66 deg should point at the left eye.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As usual with rotations, one needs to translate to the origin, then rotate, then translate back. Here, we can take the center of the image as origin.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

data_orig = misc.face()
x0,y0 = 580,300 # left eye; (xrot,yrot) should point there

def rot(image, xy, angle):
    im_rot = rotate(image,angle) 
    org_center = (np.array(image.shape[:2][::-1])-1)/2.
    rot_center = (np.array(im_rot.shape[:2][::-1])-1)/2.
    org = xy-org_center
    a = np.deg2rad(angle)
    new = np.array([org[0]*np.cos(a) + org[1]*np.sin(a),
            -org[0]*np.sin(a) + org[1]*np.cos(a) ])
    return im_rot, new+rot_center


fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

axes[0,0].imshow(data_orig)
axes[0,0].scatter(x0,y0,c="r" )
axes[0,0].set_title("original")

for i, angle in enumerate([66,-32,90]):
    data_rot, (x1,y1) = rot(data_orig, np.array([x0,y0]), angle)
    axes.flatten()[i+1].imshow(data_rot)
    axes.flatten()[i+1].scatter(x1,y1,c="r" )
    axes.flatten()[i+1].set_title("Rotation: {}deg".format(angle))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Just thought you'd like to know, the [source code for ndimage.rotate](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/interpolation.py#L728) calculates the centers of the images with a 0.5 decrement.

Comment: @unutbu I didn't think that microscopically, but you're of course right. Images, for which [that would matter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bbKL.png), are anyways not well suited to be rotated and the scatter glyphs in the new matplotlib version are anyways off by a couple of pixels. In any case, I updated the solution.